# Error in python: Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o906.collectToPython

Tags: python, pyspark, py4j

Error in python:

```
 Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o906.collectToPython.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 771.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 771.0 (TID 1350) (10.184.16.101 executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker failed to connect back.
```

In the python code, I am using `PySpark` `dataframe`. I wrote the code as:

```
#3 random users
user_subset = [559369947, 514673131, 512411198]

#Recommend top 50 products for the users
recommendations = sc.createDataFrame([(user, 0) for user in user_subset], ['user_id', 'product_id'])
recommendations = als_model.recommendForUserSubset(recommendations, 50)
recommendations.show()
```